# Uniform continous functions?

Tags: uniform-convergence

Please if someone could tell me how to show that $1\over x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.

I hope I've been clear enough, thanks.

Comment: The intuitive understanding is that as you go closer and closer to $0$, the function gets steeper and steeper.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I know what it means I just forgot how its proofed formally.

Comment: Any uniformly continuous function  on a bounded interval is bounded

Comment: It is continious on (0,1) but not uniform ontinious. Let xn=1/(n+1/2) and yn=1(n-1/2) f(x)=1/x. Let e>0.|f(xn)- f(yn)|=1, but for large enough n |xy-yn|<e

Answer (score 0):

It is continious on (0,1) but not uniform ontinious. Let $xn=1/(n+1/2)$ and $ yn=1(n-1/2) $f(x)=1/x. Let e>0.$|f(xn)- f(yn)|=1$, but for large enough n $|x_y-y_n|<e$. So $x_n$ and $y_n$ are close enough  but $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)$are not.